# TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in react js

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

My code is supposed to generate a popup of a product then add the product to the wishlist page. It gives an error that length is not defined, I think it because I misused hooks, I tried adding  const [listVariations, setListVariations] = useState(0) in place of  const [listVariations, setListVariations] = useState([]) but it still gives out same error  can someone help me sort it out thanks in advance!

```
import React, { Fragment, useContext, useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import './Sass/Index.scss'
import { WishListContext } from '../../contexts/WishListContext'
import { ProductContext } from '../../contexts/ProductContext'
import Popup from "reactjs-popup";

const Product = ({product, id, productIndex}) => {
    const{name, price, image, variation, option, unit, total} = product
    const {wishListState, wishListDispatch} = useContext(WishListContext)
    const {productState} = useContext(ProductContext)
    const [popupVariation, setPopupVariation] = useState(false)
    const [popupOption, setPopupOption] = useState(false)
    const [listVariations, setListVariations] = useState([])
    const [listOptions, setListOptions] = useState([])
    const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState({})
    const [updateToggle, setUpdateToggle] = useState(false)
   

    useEffect(()=> {
        generatePopupVariation()
        generatePopupOptions()
    }, [productState])

    const updateLocalStorage = (products) => {
        if (products.length > 0) {
            wishListDispatch({
                type:"REPLACE_WISH",
                payload: products.map(item => item)
            })
        } 
    }

    const generatePopupOptions = () => {
        const products = productState.products
        if (products.length > 0) {
            const finedProduct = products.find(item => item.id === id)
            const priceOptions = finedProduct?.data.priceOptions
            setListOptions(priceOptions && priceOptions[0].options) 
        }
    }

    const generatePopupOptionContent= () => {
        if ( listOptions.length > 0 ) {
           const filtered = listOptions.filter(item => item.is_available !== 'No')
           return filtered.map((item, index) => <li key={index}><span>{item.option}</span><span>Price: {item.price}</span><div className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => changeOption(index, item.option, item.price)} >Select</div></li>)
        }
    }

    const changeOption = (index, option, price) => {
        const action = {
            id,
            option,
            price
        }
        if (option) {
            wishListDispatch({
                type:'UPDATE_OPTION_WISH',
                action
            })
            updateLocalStorage(wishListState.products)
            modalOption('close')
        }  
    }

  
    const generatePopupVariation = () => {
        const products = productState.products
        if (products.length > 0) {
            const finedProduct = products.find(item => item.id === id)
            const priceOptions = finedProduct?.data.priceOptions
            setListVariations(priceOptions)
        }
    }

    const generatePopupVariationContent = () => {
     
     if ( listVariations.length > 0 ) {
      console.log(listVariations.length)
      return listVariations.map((item, index) => <li className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => changeVariation(index, item.variation, item.options)} key={index}>{item.variation}</li>)
   }
    }

    const changeVariation = (index, variation, options) => {
        const action = {
            id,
            variation
        }
        if (variation) {
            wishListDispatch({
                type:'UPDATE_VARIATION_WISH',
                action
            })
            updateLocalStorage(wishListState.products)
            modalVariation('close')
        }  
    }
    
    const handleRemove = () => {
        if (wishListState) {
            if( wishListState.products.length > 0) {
                wishListDispatch({
                    type: 'REMOVE_WISH',
                    payload: productIndex
                })
            }
        }
    }
    const handleUnit = (control) => {
        if (wishListState) {
            if( wishListState.products.length > 0) {
                wishListDispatch({
                    type: 'ADD_UNIT_WISH',
                    payload: {index: productIndex, control:control}
                })
            }
        }
    }
    const modalVariation = action => {
        if (action === 'open') {
            setPopupVariation(true)
        } else if (action === 'close') {
            setPopupVariation(false)
        }
    }
    const modalOption = action => {
        if (action === 'open') {
            setPopupOption(true)
        } else if (action === 'close') {
            setPopupOption(false)
        }
    }

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <Popup
                open={popupVariation}
                closeOnDocumentClick
                onClose={()=> modalVariation('close')}
            >
                <div className="popup-content"> 
                    <ul>
                        {generatePopupVariationContent()}
                    </ul>
                    <span onClick={() => modalVariation('close')}>X</span>
                </div>
            </Popup>
            <Popup
                open={popupOption}
                closeOnDocumentClick
                onClose={()=> modalOption('close')}
            >
                <div className="popup-content"> 
                    <ul>
                        {generatePopupOptionContent()}
                    </ul>
                    <span onClick={() => modalOption('close')}>X</span>
                </div>
            </Popup>
                <div className="card">
                    <div className="card-wrapper">
                        <div className="left">
                            <img className="card-img" src={ image } alt={ name } />
                        </div>
                        <div className="right">
                            <div className="card-remove" onClick={handleRemove}>
                                <i className="times" name="close"></i>
                            </div>
                            <h4 className="card-title">{ name }</h4>
                            { variation && <p className="card-variation"><span>Variation:</span><span>{variation} <span onClick={()=> modalVariation('open')} className="change-variation"><ion-icon name="create"></ion-icon></span></span> </p>}
                            { option && <p className="card-option"><span>Option:</span><span> { option }  <span onClick={()=> modalOption('open')} className="change-option"><ion-icon name="create"></ion-icon></span></span></p>}
                            <div className="card-unit"><span>Qty:</span>
                                <div className="card-units-wrapper">
                                    <i className="plus" name="add" onClick={() => handleUnit('+')}></i>
                                    <div className="card-units">{unit}</div>
                                    <i className="minus" name="remove" onClick={() => handleUnit('-')}></i>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <p className="card-price"><span>Price:</span><span> {price} </span></p>
                            <p className="card-total"><span>Total:</span> <span>{total} </span></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </Fragment>
    )
}

export default Product
```

ProductContext.js

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer } from 'react'
import ProductReducer from '../reducers/ProductReducer'

export const ProductContext = createContext()

const initState = {
    products: []
}

const ProductProvider = props => {
    const [ productState, productDispatch ] = useReducer(ProductReducer, initState)
    const value = {productState, productDispatch}
    return (
        <ProductContext.Provider value={value}>
            {props.children}
        </ProductContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default ProductProvider
```

ProductReducer.js

```
const ProductReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "LOAD_PRODUCTS":
            return {...state, products: [...action.payload]}
        case "ADD_PRODUCT":
            return {...state, products: [...state.products, action.payload]}
        default:
            return state
    }
}
export default ProductReducer;
```

WishlistContext.js

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer } from 'react'
import WishListReducer from '../reducers/WishListReducer'
export const WishListContext = createContext()

const initState = {
    products: [],
    select_variation:null
}
const WishListProvider = props => {
    const [ wishListState, wishListDispatch ] = useReducer(WishListReducer, initState)
    const value = {wishListState, wishListDispatch }
    return (
        <WishListContext.Provider value={value}>
            {props.children}
        </WishListContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default WishListProvider
```

WishlistReducer.js

```
const WishListReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "ADD_WISH":
            return addWish(state, action)
        case "REPLACE_WISH":
            return replaceWish(state, action)
        case "REMOVE_WISH":
            return removeWish(state, action)
        case "ADD_UNIT_WISH":
            return unitWish(state, action)
        case "UPDATE_VARIATION_WISH":
            return updateVariation(state, action)
        case "UPDATE_OPTION_WISH":
            return updateOption(state, action)
        default:
            return state
    }
}

const addWish = (state, action) => {
    localStorage.setItem('wish-list', JSON.stringify({...state, products: [...state.products, action.payload] }))
    return {...state, products: [...state.products, action.payload] }
}

const replaceWish = (state, action) => {
    localStorage.setItem('wish-list', JSON.stringify({...state, products: [...action.payload] }))
    return {...state, products: [...action.payload] }
}

const removeWish = (state, action) => {
    const copyState = {...state }
    copyState.products.splice(action.payload, 1);
    localStorage.setItem('wish-list', JSON.stringify({...state, products: [...copyState.products] }))
    return {...state, products: [...copyState.products] }
}

const unitWish = (state, action) => {
    const copyState = {...state }
    const index = copyState.products[action.payload.index]
    const ctrl = action.payload.control
    const unit = index.unit
    const price = index.price
    if (ctrl == "+") {
        index.unit = Number(unit) + 1
        index.total = Number(price) * (Number(unit) + 1)
    }
    if (ctrl == "-") {
        if (Number(unit) <= 1) {
            index.unit = 1
        } else {
            index.unit = Number(unit) - 1
            index.total = Number(price) * (Number(unit) - 1)
        }
    }
    localStorage.setItem('wish-list', JSON.stringify({...state, products: [...copyState.products] }))
    return {...state, products: [...copyState.products] }
}

const updateVariation = (state, action) => {
    const id = action.action.id
    const variation = action.action.variation
    const copyState = {...state }
    const product = copyState.products.find(item => item.id == id)
    product.variation = variation
    return {...state, products: [...copyState.products] }
}

const updateOption = (state, action) => {
    const id = action.action.id
    const option = action.action.option
    const price = action.action.price
    const copyState = {...state }
    const product = copyState.products.find(item => item.id === id)
    product.option = option
    product.price = price
    product.total = product.unit * price
    return {...state, products: [...copyState.products] }
}


export default WishListReducer;
```

Comment: Could you specify which line in the code is throwing the error? You have 8 instances of `.length` and it would be helpful to be more specific.

Comment: You have two contexts that can be triggering this issue, given you check `length` from their `products` property

Comment: Show us your `productState.products` structure.

Comment: @AntonioErdeljac  listVariations.length > 0 , this one

Answer (score 1):

Basically, some of the content used with .length is undefined. The best way to learn which one is `undefined`, is to use `typeof`. You can use `typeof variableName` to determine what is the type of the variable. If some of the types in the code are not List or Array, it will create an error. To debug, you can put `alert("Type is not valid")` combined with methods to see. (Btw we are not having those data and determine what is errored.)

Comment: I already did that, a variable type is an object, then as I mentioned earlier I tried replacing  const [listVariations, setListVariations] = useState(0) in place of const [listVariations, setListVariations] = useState([])  as .length cannot be applied to objects

Comment: Would you try useState(new Array())